# Blazor wasm HotReload General Exception

Tags: blazor-webassembly, hot-reload

Blazor wasm hosted, running with HotReload enabled. Saving any razor file results in an error dialog

> General Exception This error was not expected. Your debugged process might be corrupted....

The browser console shows a series of errors summarised below:

```
       Unhandled Exception:

blazor.webassembly.js:1 
        
       System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.


blazor.webassembly.js:1 
        
          at 

blazor.webassembly.js:1 
        
          at Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.DotNetDispatcher.InvokeSynchronously(JSRuntime 

blazor.webassembly.js:1 
        
          at Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.DotNetDispatcher.Invoke(JSRuntime jsRuntime, 

blazor.webassembly.js:1 
        
          at 

aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js:138 
        
       Error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.HotReload.WebAssemblyHotReload.ApplyHotReloadDelta(:7017/String moduleIdString, Byte[] metadataDelta, Byte[] ilDelta, Byte[] pdbBytes)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.DotNetDispatcher.InvokeSynchronously(:7017/JSRuntime jsRuntime, DotNetInvocationInfo& callInfo, IDotNetObjectReference objectReference, String argsJson)
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.DotNetDispatcher.Invoke(:7017/JSRuntime jsRuntime, DotNetInvocationInfo& invocationInfo, String argsJson)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Services.DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime.InvokeDotNet(:7017/String assemblyName, String methodIdentifier, String dotNetObjectId, String argsJson)
    at qi (dotnet.7.0.3.pe05f8nz0f.js:5:80613)
    at Ji (dotnet.7.0.3.pe05f8nz0f.js:5:80497)
    at _Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_InvokeDotNet (_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_InvokeDotNet:30:5)
    at Object.invokeDotNetFromJS (blazor.webassembly.js:1:45224)
    at g (blazor.webassembly.js:1:1621)
    at e.invokeMethod (blazor.webassembly.js:1:2670)
    at Vt.Ke._internal.applyHotReload (blazor.webassembly.js:1:58767)
    at aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js:136:33
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at applyBlazorDeltas (aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js:134:12)
(anonymous) @ aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js:138
applyBlazorDeltas @ aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js:134
BlazorHotReloadDeltav1 @ aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js:46
connection.onmessage @ aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js:53
```

More info:
I have HotReload working in a vanilla Blazor hosted site (new solution). So this feels v. much like something "wrong" with my implementation however.....

- Comparing with the vanilla app, I cannnot see anything amiss with Program.cs, index.html, .net versions etc - though investigations are ongoing

I'm running out of ideas, can someone suggest what to try next?

Comment: Which browser are you using? I was having similar issues with Chrome ("General Exception", but I wasn't seeing anything in the browser console). Switching the browser in VS to Edge made all problems go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and fixed it by resetting my `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable in my `launchSettings.json` back to `Development`. There's also a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39269) for this bug.

Comment: Blazor seem v. particular in respect of appsettings names. The advice is use "Development" and "Production" exactly and not Dev, prod etc. Many thanks @R4pt0r